# ¿Alguien puede ayudarme con este error, por favor?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Me aparece un error en mysql dice "unknown column 'Cuota' in OLD". Ya he mirado y todo está bien, no se qué sucede; pondré el código por si alguien puede ayudarme, muchas gracias.

```
create table AntiguaCuota(
Oficina varchar(2) not null,
Cuota decimal not null,
Ventas decimal not null
);

delimiter $

create trigger Update_Oficina
before update
on Oficina
for each row
begin
   insert into AntiguaCuota(Oficina, Cuota, Ventas) values (old.oficina,
   old.Cuota,old.ventas);
end $

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Bienvenida a stackoverflow.Te está diciendo que no conoce tu columna cuota en la tabla old, te aseguraste de que está todo bien con esa columna y tabla?

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio. Dado que el _trigger_ está corriendo sobre la tabla `oficina`, lo que significa el mensaje de error es que dicha tabla no tiene una columna llamada `cuota`.

Comment: @mourazo. Si, ya me había asegurado de que estuviera todo bien con esa columna

Comment: @jachguate no sabia, muchas gracias me ha servido mucho tu ayuda